# Connecting server with router

Tags: 14.04, networking

If i have a router and a server, the interface going out from the router has an ip address of 10.0.2.1 and the interface on the server is 10.0.2.10. If i want to add three more servers to the router but have them on the same network what ip addresses would i give to all the interfaces.

Comment: you can use any not used ip in the range of the same network depending on the subnetmask you have applied. In case of 255.255.255.0 subnet that would mean you can pick 10.0.2.2-254 (excluding the used ip 1 of the router and 10 of the server).

Comment: @Syfyaan B What is your subnet mask?

Comment: My subnet is 255.255.255.0

Comment: @SufyaanB I reversed your edit (looked like you removed a bit too much).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your network setup but a safe (mostly) bet is:

- Network 10.0.2.0-10.0.2.255
- Router 10.0.2.1
- Server (existing) 10.0.2.10
- Server (new1) 10.0.2.11
- Server (new2) 10.0.2.12
- Server (new3) 10.0.2.13

Comment: what ip addresses would i give the interfaces on the router?

Comment: As far as I know that will not be needed. You need to point your servers to use the router as default gateway. Also make sure that you set static IP addresses on your servers so if your router has DHCP it does not assign random addresses.

Comment: If you would like to you can reserve the server network adapter MAC addresses on your router to these specific new IP addresses so they would be reserved and not leased by other devices connecting to the network.

Comment: I am using VMware so its virtual

Comment: Then you are either looking at using Bridged network on the network adapter settings in VMware for the VM's or you can put all the environment (the servers) inside a custom virtual network also done under network adapter settings in VMware.

Comment: i dont understand what the ip addresses of the routers 4 interfaces would be

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment but you said your Router has the IP 10.0.2.1
It only needs this IP. As soon as you make a SetUp like @XenAinars recomended
your Router should be able to communicate with the servers.

With a Networkmask of 255.255.255.0 means that you can give your Servers ANY IPs in the range 10.0.2.X where X can be 2-254
(because 1 is already the router, and 0 and 255 are reserved for the network itself)

Anyway a more secure way to set this up would be to cut the Networkmask actually only to the needed ammount of IPs .. in this case would be 5 IPs -> use Netmask 255.255.255.248 and give them the IPs

- Router 10.0.2.5
- Server1 10.0.2.1
- Server2 10.0.2.2
- Server3 10.0.2.3
- Server4 10.0.2.4

This way no one could like give himself the IP e.g. 10.0.2.125 and connect to your Servers and Router